# New bricks disorder

Tags: c++

You have n bricks arranged in a line on the table. There is exactly one letter on each of them. Your task is to rearrange those bricks so that letters on them create some specified inscription. While rearanging you can only swap adjacent bricks with specified letters (you are given m pairs (a1,b1),...,(am,bm) and you are only allowed to swap bricks with ai on one of them and bi on the second, for some i=1,..,m). You should check if it is possible to accomplish this - and if it is - calculate minimal needed number of swaps.

Input

There is a single integer c on the first line of input. Then c test cases follow: each of them consists of two lines of small letters (a..z) with lengths not exceeding 100000 (descriptions of starting and ending configurations), one integer m in the next line and then m lines with two letters ai,bi in each of them.

Output

For each test case you should print -1 if it is not possible to rearrange bricks or the minimal number of swaps if it is possible (if so, output this value modulo 232).

```
  Input:
  4
  ab
 ba
 0
 abc
 cba
 3
 ab
 cb
 ca
 cabbbc
 cbabbc
 1
 ab
 abba
 baab
 1
 ab

 Output:
-1
 3
 1
 2
```

i am not understand the question can any one help me to understand the testcases no need of guiding me in giving hints and algorithms just explain me the question,thanx

Comment: Which part of the description don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got 4 test cases.

```
Case 1:
start config: `ab`
end config:   `ba`
allowed adjacent swaps: none
result: -1 - without any allowed swap, you can't get from `ab` to `ba`

Case 2:
start config: `abc`
end config: `cba`
allowed adjacent swaps: `(ab)`,`(cb)`,`(ca)`
result: 3
example solution: `abc -> (cb)@(1,2) -> acb -> (ca)@(0,1) -> cab -> (ab)@(1,2) -> cba`

Case 3:
start config: `cabbbc`
end config: `cbabbc`
allowed adjacent swaps: `(ab)`
result: 3
example solution: `cabbbc -> (ab)@(1,2) -> cabbbc`


Case 4:
start config: `abba`
end config: `baab`
allowed adjacent swaps: `(ab)`
result: 2
example solution: `abba -> (ab)@(2,3) -> abab -> (ab)@(0,1) -> baab`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
4 - 4 testcases
(now two lines which were said, they define strings to swap one into another)
ab
ba
0 - zero strings which define bricks

Now, you can't rearrange nothing, because you have no strigns. return -1.

Now the secons testcase:
(two lines which define strings to trasform one into another)
abc
cba
3 - three bricks
ab
cb
ca
And above we ahve three bricks. So we can, to my understanding, swap these bricks letters, so swap a with b, c with b, and c with a, so basically all possible swaps are allowed).

Third testcase - analogical to the second, but you're only allowed to swap "a" with "b".
cabbbc
cbabbc
1
ab

And so on...

abba
baab
1
ab
```

That's my understanding of the task.

Answer (score 0):

A test case is a start and finish position (two lines of characters) followed by a number. The number describes how many possible transitions there are. Then there are the possible transitions. So in your example, the first test case is "How many steps does it take to go from ab to ba when there are no letters you can swap?" (The answer -1 is the "not possible" answer.) The second test case is "How many steps does it take to go from abc to cba if you can swap ab, cb, or ca?" The answer is 3. The third test case is "How many steps does it take to go from cabbbc to cbabbc if you can swap ab?" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the test cases (in rearranged order)

```
ab
ba
0
```

You can't come from "ab" to "ba" because no swaps are allowed => output `-1`

```
cabbbc
cbabbc
1
ab
```

You can swap adjacent `a` and `b`, well, just do it once on the second and third character. => output `1`

```
abba
baab
1
ab
```

Same here, the first two and the last two, makes two swaps => output `2`

```
abc
cba
3
ab
cb
ca
```

You can't swap `a` and `c` directly because they are not adjacent. Instead, swap `a` with `b` and get `bac`. Then, swap `a` with `c` and get `bca`. At the very last, swap `b` with `c` and get `cba` => output `3`

If you can swap "ab" to "ba", you can also swap "ba" to "ab". This wasn't obvious from the task description but the sample testcase makes this clear.